# Why the values from Input are not being sent to api

Tags: node.js, react-native, express, axios

I need to pass the `values` from `TextInput` to `API`, but what i have is this object below, taken from `console.log`:

```
Object {
  "__v": 0,
  "_id": "5e4422f5c6fc7b323c71db52",
}
```

It's empty. I don't know what i'm doing wrong. I'm using Node.js with Express and Axios on Backend.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

import api from '../services/api';

function CadastroChild({ navigation }){

    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [idade, setIdade] = useState('');
    const [peso, setPeso] = useState('');
    const [comprimento, setComprimento] = useState('');
    const [temperatura, setTemperatura] = useState('');

    async function addChild(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        const response = await api.post('/children', {
            name,
            idade,
            peso,
            comprimento,
            temperatura
        })

        console.log(response.data);

    }

    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.childForm}>
            <Text style={styles.textInput}>Nome Completo:</Text>
            <TextInput 
                style={styles.childInput}
                placeholder="Nome da criança"
                placeholderTextColor="#999"
                autoCapitalize="words"
                autoCorrect={false}
                required
                value={name}
                onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
            />
            <Text style={styles.textInput}>Idade:</Text>
            <TextInput 
                style={styles.childInput}
                placeholder="Digite a idade"
                placeholderTextColor="#999"
                keyboardType="numeric"
                required
                value={idade}
                onChange={e => setIdade(e.target.value)}
            />
            <Text style={styles.textInput}>Peso (kg):</Text>
            <TextInput 
                style={styles.childInput}
                placeholder="Digite o peso"
                placeholderTextColor="#999"
                keyboardType="numeric"
                required
                value={peso}
                onChange={e => setPeso(e.target.value)}
            />
            <Text style={styles.textInput}>Comprimento (m):</Text>
            <TextInput 
                style={styles.childInput}
                placeholder="Digite o comprimento"
                placeholderTextColor="#999"
                keyboardType="numeric"
                required
                value={comprimento}
                onChange={e => setComprimento(e.target.value)}
            />
            <Text style={styles.textInput}>Temperatura (ºC):</Text>
            <TextInput 
                style={styles.childInput}
                placeholder="Digite a temperatura"
                placeholderTextColor="#999"
                keyboardType="numeric"
                required
                value={temperatura}
                onChange={e => setTemperatura(e.target.value)}
            />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.viewButton}>
            <TouchableOpacity 
                style={styles.goButton}
                onPress={() => { 
                    addChild();
                    navigation.navigate('Menu'); 
                }} 
            ><Text style={styles.textButton}>Cadastrar</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        </View>

    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({...})

export default CadastroChild;
```

I'm new using React Native and Node.js.

Comment: I think we'll need to see the relevant code in `../services/api`